# filter ng-repeat by function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I would like to iterate over an array using `ng-repeat` and filter the contained objects depending on a function property. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gjukbBINGWlGHBdWiHaB?p=preview)

This means i have an object like this:

```
vm.show1 = function(){
  return true;
};    
var object1 = {label: 'Object1', show: vm.show1};
```

and would like to filter it something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in ctrl.objects | filter:{show:true}">{{object.label}}</div>
```

Obviously in the above example `vm.show1` is a function (and thus does not equal `true`). Is there a way to make the filter call the function and evaluate the result or do i have to write a custom filter?

Edit: Is this even possible at all? If angular doesn't handle the dirty-checking out of the box the filter wouldn't know when it needs to reevaluate the function.

Comment: So you want to execute a function on every object, and see if it should be visible or not?

Comment: yes basically that's it. I want to place (more or less) complicated statements within a function and make ng-repeat look for the result of that function. The resulting view should be the same as if i list the elements manually and wrap every single one into an ng-if block with such a function.

Comment: then why not just use `ng-if`? `$scope` problems?

Comment: because i would need to manually list the content of my array or wrap everything in directives. Both is way more code than if i could just use`ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is with a custom filter function:

```
$scope.filterFn = function(object)
{
    //if true, rendered in ng-repeat
    //if false, not rendered in ng-repeat
    return object.show1(); 
};

<div ng-repeat="object in ctrl.objects | filter:filterFn">
```